# Sweetalert not working when added runat="server" in button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sweetalert

I have a button whose id is `alert_demo_1`.

Sweetalert doesn't works when i have added `runat="server"`.

(It works properly when removed `runat="server"`)

script ->

```
<script src="../../assets/js/plugin/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$('#alert_demo_1').click(function(e) {
                swal('Good job!', {
                    buttons: {                  
                        confirm: {
                            className : 'btn btn-success'
                        }
                    },
                });
            }); 
</script>

<button id="alert_demo_1" class="btn btn-success" runat="server" 
type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute runat="server" to any element, it will become an HTML server element. such elements called Web Server Controls that are group of controls derived directly from the System.Web.UI.WebControls base class. (.NET)

These elements map directly to html tags and without runat="server" it cannot access the control in code behind.
[reference](http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/server-control.htm)

you just need to modify the event handler from

```
$('#alert_demo_1').click(function(e) {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#alert_demo_1', function(e) {
```

Comment: I solved it by replacing #alert_demo_1 to '#<%=alert_demo_1.ClientID%>'

Comment: yes that's the right way to do it, you can also do it as 
$('[id$=alert_demo_1]').click(function(e) {

Answer (score 0):

When you use server side controls, you cannot access them as a normal HTML control in jquery. But you can control it as below:

put the `runat="server"` on button

and access button in jquery as below:

```
$('[id$=alert_demo_1]').click(function(e) {
```

or

```
$('#<%=alert_demo_1.ClientID%>').click(function(e) {
```